# Sliding time window query in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My data is organised in the following way:

```
(:Node {id:<int>})-[:INTERACTED_WITH {time:<epoch integer>}]->(:Node {id:<int>})
```

with

```
CREATE INDEX ON :INTERACTED_WITH(time)
```

I.e. nodes interacting with other nodes at specific times.

The query I want to make is a sliding window one. I am simply counting the interactions that any two nodes had during a window that slides through a longer time interval. For a single window the query is:

```
MATCH (a:Node)-[r:INTERACTED_WITH]->(b:Node) WHERE
r.time >= <window_start_time> AND
r.time < <window_start_time + window_size>
RETURN a.id, b.id, COUNT(r)
```

I'm now doing the full query programmatically, in a while loop, but I find it very slow.

What I'm looking for is essentially an equivalent to SQL-like sliding window queries where you can create a series of window start times on the fly (as a temporary table) and query based on this the tables in the database.

Is there something similar in Cypher?

Comment: It doesn't impact your question, but I believe that your CREATE INDEX statement doesn't do anything. Schema indices are only made for labels on nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you may be able to do this. As an example, you could write

```
UNWIND range(<start time>, <end time>, <step size>) AS t
MATCH (a:Node)-[r:INTERACTED_WITH]->(b:Node)
WHERE r.time >= t AND r.time < t + window_size
RETURN a.id, b.id, COUNT(r)
```

You could also create a set of temporary nodes that have the window boundaries as properties. Assuming you have those, you could write

```
MATCH (c:Window)
MATCH (a:Node)-[r:INTERACTED_WITH]->(b:Node)
WHERE r.time >= c.start_time AND r.time < c.end_time
RETURN a.id, b.id, COUNT(r)
```

Once you are done you could delete the :Window nodes.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, both options are still slower than doing the single query multiple times programmatically, but it is exactly what I was looking for.